# Google colab Error: How do I fix error of 'no such file directory'?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

```
   2008         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   2009 
-> 2010         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   2011         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   2012 

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/drive/My Drive/Stagnation list.csv'
```

Comment: What is the value of `src`.  Does it contain the name of a file?

Comment: I am new to python.....where can i look for it?